# How to generate random pairs

Tags: ruby

I have an array like this:

```
a = [["A", "1"], ["B", "2"], ["C", "3"], ["D", "4"], ["E", "5"]]
```

I need to create a list of random pairs, removing the new ones that are similar to the previous ones.

Example:

```
a = [["B", "4"], ["A", "2"], ["E", "3"], ["C", "5"]]
```

Not accepted :

```
["D", "4"]
```

Comment: can you explain what counts as similar?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Will `[]` be a solution (assuming all pairs were similar to the previous ones)?

Comment: the code is simply the Array! 
yes, empity array can be a solution

Comment: How many pairs output should have?

Comment: Voting to close because the question does explain what "similar" means.  The accepted answer seems to know, but it's not at all obvious to me.

Comment: output should have the same elements of the original array excluding duplicates

Comment: I understand the question, but only because you selected @sawa's answer. You need to edit to clarify. I suggest you simplify by dropping the last two elements of `a`. Then say something like, "I wish to create an array consisting of all pairs `[c,d]` such that `c` is the first element of one of the pairs of `a`,  `d` is the second element of one of the pairs of `a`, and `[c,d]` is not an element of `a`.  The desired result is `[["A","2"],["A","3"],["B","1"],["B","3],["C","1"],["C","2"]]`"  Randomly selecting elements of the new array is not central to the question, so I suggest you drop that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That is not equivalent. In your definition, the created array always has the same size as the original, but the OP wants to allow some elements to be missing.

Comment: @sawa, I don't understand. The created array will have `a.size*(a.size-1)` elements, and from that the OP can draw any number of elements randomly.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Not sure about your formula `a.size*(a.size-1)`.

Comment: @sawa, I forgot about the possibility of dups of `a.map(&:first)` or `a.map(&:last)`. I guess it should be `a.map(&:first).uniq.size*(a.map(&:last).uniq.size-1)` pairs that can be constructed from `a` that are not elements of `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
k, v = a.transpose
a = [k, v.shuffle].transpose - a
```

Comment: Kudos for clarifying the question as well as providing a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to shuffle both letters and numbers (if order is important), then use:

```
letters, numbers = a.transpose
letters.shuffle.zip(numbers.shuffle)
```

If you want to remove duplicates with the original, then:

```
letters.shuffle.zip(numbers.shuffle) - a
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not stated how many elements output should have.  Below is an example that will work for `n` output elements:

```
a = [["A", "1"], ["B", "2"], ["C", "3"], ["D", "4"], ["E", "5"]]

n = 3
v1, v2 = a.map(&:first), a.map(&:last)
r = (v1.flat_map {|i| v2.map {|j| [i, j]}} - a).sample(n)
#=> [["A", "3"], ["D", "1"], ["D", "5"]]
```